# How often does a element appear in a column of a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I am having trouble figuring out how to count how often a element appears in a column of my array. I know how to count the row but not the column. This is my current loop I made to count how often character A appears in the first column.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    char[][] answers = {
        {'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'},
        {'D', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'},
        {'E', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'},
        {'C', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'},
        {'A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'},
        {'B', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'},
        {'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'},
        {'E', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'D'}};

    System.out.println("Row length is " + answers.length);
    System.out.println("Column length is " + answers[2].length);

    for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        int letterA = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < answers[i].length; j++) {
            //  System.out.print(j+""+i+" ");
            if (answers[i][j] == 'A') {
                letterA++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of A in column " + i + " is " + letterA);
    }
}
```

}

This code counts A for the entire array instead of just the column.

What should I do to see how often A appears in the second column as well? My array has a total of 5 columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print the statement inside `i` loop to get the count per colum

```
for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
      int letterA=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < answers[i].length; j++) {
            if (answers[j][i] == 'A') {
                letterA++;
            }
        }
       System.out.println("Number of A in column "+i+" is "+letterA);
    }
```

[**Demo1**](http://ideone.com/P829KG)(for same rows and columns count)

Btw to check column you have to change the index to `if (answers[j][i] == 'A') {`

If you want to check only for one column do

```
    int colIndex = 0;
    int letterA = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < answers[i].length; j++) {
        if (answers[j][colIndex] == 'A') {
            letterA++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of A in column " + colIndex + " is " + letterA);
```

For different row and column count you can do

```
for (int i = 0; i < answers[0].length; i++) {
    int letterA = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < answers.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + "" + i + " ");
        if (answers[j][i] == 'A') {
            letterA++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of A in column " + i + " is " + letterA);
}
```

[**Demo2**](http://ideone.com/Rxkudh)

Comment: @downvoter can you explain whats wrong with my solution?

Comment: I downvoted because your algorithm has `O(n^2)` complexity. We know which column we want to search in and you did not use this information in your answer.

Comment: So you downvoted because you don't like that I downvoted? Figures.

Comment: What should I do if I get an Index out of bound exception error. My array has 8 rows and 10 columns. I get an exception at 8

Comment: @Cory can you update your current code by editing your question.Also did you check the demo?

Comment: I just get the error if I use   `answer[j][i]` instead of `answer[i][j]`

Comment: code is updated with my current code after checking out the demo.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense now. I kept getting the out of bound error for all the codes I tried. I just had the loop wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a double-nested loop, you are going to go through all the columns. If you want to just go through one particular column, you only need one loop

```
int i = 1, //first column
    letterA=0;//initialize the counter
for (int j = 0; j < answers[i].length; j++) {//go through column 1
  if (answers[i][j] == 'A') {//check for 'A'
    letterA++;
  }
}
System.out.println(letterA);
```

Comment: It's funny, because someone on this thread downvoted the answers as soon as they popped up.

Comment: @MuratK. Don't know why, wasn't me.

Comment: It was me beacuse they both have quadratic complexity which is unacceptable since we know which column/row we want to search in. Your answer is correct thus I did not downvote.

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't I need another loop to check all my columns?

Comment: If you want to check **all** your columns you need a nested loop.

Comment: @Cory You mentioned you only want to check your first column. If we only need to check the first column, we only need one loop

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want to check all of the columns.

Comment: you index are wrong it should be `answers[j][i]` if you are going through column and also for first column `i` should be zero not `1`

Answer (score 1):

Documenting your code shows exactly why:

```
// loops through the rows 
for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    // loops through the columns
    for (int j = 0; j < answers[i].length; j++) {
        // check the cell at the current row and column
        if (answers[i][j] == 'A') {
            letterA++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(letterA);
```

So don't do the second loop, just do  `if (answers[i][0] == 'A')` to check the first column, etc.

Comment: So you downvoted because you don't like that I downvoted? Figures.

Comment: What? I downvoted nobody on this thread. Are you sure you're commenting on the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a nested loop for that. If your array is something like this:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'],
 ['B', 'A', 'C'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

Where the nested array(s) represent(s) a column you simply do this:

```
int columnIndex = 0; // first column
int columnLength = answers[columnIndex].length;

for(int i = columnLength; i < columnLengh; i++) {
    if (answers[columnIndex][i] == 'A') {
        letterA++;
    }
}
```

Comment: you index are wrong it should be `answers[i][columnIndex]` if you are going through column

Comment: @AdamArold same happend to my answer... and our codes both represent how to count element apperance in 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

i think it would look something like this:

```
 package lala;

 import java.util.Random;

public class ElementsCount {
private char[][] arr;
private int size;
public ElementsCount(int size){
    this.arr = new char[size][size];
    this.size = size;
}
public void fillArray(){
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = 0 ; i<size;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
            arr[i][j]=r.nextInt()<r.nextInt()?(char)(r.nextInt(2)+66):(char)(r.nextInt(2)+66);
        }
    }
}
public void printArray(){
    String[] out = new String[size];
    for(int column=0;column<this.size;column++){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int row=0;row<this.size;row++){
            sb.append(this.arr[column][row]);
        }
        out[column]=sb.toString();
    }
    for(String o : out){
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
public void countColumnElement(int col, char element){
    int elementApperance=0;
    for(int i=0;i<this.size;i++){
        if(element==arr[i][col]){
            elementApperance++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(element+" : "+elementApperance);
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    ElementsCount e = new ElementsCount(10);
    e.fillArray();
    e.printArray();
    e.countColumnElement(0, 'B');
 }
 }
```